# How do I get my question answered if I don’t have enough points for a bounty?

Tags: discussion, support, unanswered-questions

For my question, [In following example does d converge?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253820/for-the-following-example-does-d-converge), I’m unsure whether my question will be answered. It’s only been a few hours and someone has upvoted but no one has left a comment.

How do I make sure someone will answer my question if I don’t have enough points for a bounty?

Comment: (1) Write a more interesting question and/or title that appeals to a wider audience, (2) hope that you'll hook someone that loves the subject matter (which works on even poorly written questions), (3) Have more patience, and (4) earn more points by helping others.

Comment: Most questions are answered without the inducement  of bounties.  Your question could attract more readers, I believe, if its title stated clearly what you seek to accomplish.  "Compute my example" tells a reader nothing.  I suggest you also replace the mathematical discussion by a simple explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I edited my post. Is this better?

Comment: Yes, it is.  However, remember that many readers proficient in Mathematica are not mathematicians, and your introductory discussion may not be meaningful to them.

Comment: The problem I face when approaching your question is that I need to read the lot before I can decide if you are asking something I can help you with.  Either highlight the core question and what's going wrong or make it part of the first paragraph. It's good to have the context, but such context should not obscure the question. Also, simpler questions are more likely to be answered, so simplifying the problem can help.

Comment: @rhermans I highlighted the core question. It may difficult to answer so I added examples to the bottom of the post.

Comment: Nice, I started a bounty for you. I may need your input to allocate the bounty if you get a suitable answer.